# Should Simulink if-else block run faster than calling equivalent Matlab function?

Tags: matlab, performance, simulink

I've been modeling different possibilities of obtaining a decision in form of an Enum to compare them, expecting library functions of Simulink performing better than implementing the same functionality calling Matlab functions.

According to [this Matlab article](https://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/improving-simulation-performance-in-simulink.html) interpreted Matlab functions usually perform worse than their library counterparts due to passing through multiple software layers.

For my tests I modeled two systems calculating an output value based on an input signal and ran them for the same number of time steps with a Profiler attached.

The [implementation using Matlab function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrDPH.png) took 16s to execute, while the [implementation using library blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbJG6.png) took 566s.

Why does the simulink model using the if-else block run significantly slower? Or is there something wrong with my profiling approach?

I'd be grateful for any insights.

Comment: It's probably to do with the merging. In this case, you are not replacing a function block with its compiled counterpart, you are replacing a function block with 3 triggered subsystems and a merge.

Comment: Thank you, that might explain it

Comment: Even so, I would not expect a 3500% processing time increase for such a simple model, so something seems wrong here. That library block version should be pretty quick still. Check there aren't other things at play, such as the ensuring both runs use the same fixed step size.

Comment: As @Wolfie says, there's something not right about that timing.  It may be related to the solver, but it may also be that by default, Simulink performs [Block Reduction](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/block-reduction.html).  I.e. it does not execute blocks that are in a signal path that ends in things like termination blocks. As such you may find that the MATLAB implementation is in effect not actually doing anything.  Re-run your timing with a Scope or To Workspace block instead of a Terminator Block.  This will also allow you to validate that both models give the same output.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I replaced the terminator blocks with simout-blocks and set the same fixed step size with the same solver for both simulations. Now I am getting a run time of 29.28s for the Matlab function and a run time of 31.91 for the simulation using library blocks, which I guess is closer to their relative perfomances in a larger simulation. Do you have other suggestions for a more meaningfull profling of simulation snippets?